# LSTM network in R for time series prediction

Tags: r, time-series, lstm

I have an univariate monthly time series of size 64. I'd like to make a multi-step forecast - the last three month values (266, 286 and 230) - using the remaining months as the training set.

```
data <- c(113,  55,  77, 114,  73,  72,  75, 135,  84,  66, 167, 93,  83, 
          164,  76,  97, 148,  74,  76, 173,  70,  86, 167,  37,   1,  49,  
          48,37, 117, 178, 167, 177, 295, 167, 224, 225, 198, 217, 220, 175, 
          360, 289, 209, 369, 287, 249, 336, 219, 288, 248, 370, 296, 337, 
          246, 377, 324, 288, 367, 309, 128, 382, 266, 286, 230)
```

In order to model a LSTM network I am shaping the training/testing data the following way:

```
X_train = [55,6,1] # 6 timesteps (t-6,t-5,t-4,t-3,t-2,t-1)
Y_train = [55,3,1] # forecast horizon (t+1,t+2,t+3)
X_test  = [1,6,1]  
Y_test  = [1,3,1]
```

However, when I set up the LSTM as below I get an error

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_16 to have 
shape (6, 1) but got array with shape (3, 1)
```

LSTM Model

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>%
  layer_lstm(
              units = 32, 
              batch_input_shape  = c(1, 6, 1),
              dropout = 0.2,
              recurrent_dropout = 0.2,
              return_sequences = TRUE
  ) %>% time_distributed(layer_dense(units = 1))

  model %>%
      compile(loss = FLAGS$loss, optimizer = optimizer, metrics = 
              list("mean_squared_error"))

  history <- model %>% fit(x = X_train,
                           y = Y_train,
                           batch_size = 1,
                           epochs = 100,
                           callbacks = callbacks)
```

I am struggling with this error. Does anybody know the conceptual mistake of this modeling? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With so few data you will probably not exploit the benefit of an LSTM neural network. I recommend you to use SARIMA or HW from forecast package. If you have some non-literariness between the lags you can also build a data set with the more relevant lags and with the seasonal component extracted using fourier series and train a randomForest model.

Regarding your question I think that your arrays has no the right dimension and therefore you need to reshape them.

I am not an expert with LSTM neural networks but probably the link below can help you:

https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2018-06-25-sunspots-lstm/

BR